# Mikrotik отправить конкретный ip через второй isp

Tags: route, mikrotik

Как один конкретный ip локальной сети выпустить из резервного провайдера, чтоб именно эта машина выходила в сеть только через второй провайдер. Не соображу как.

Answer (score 0):

```
/ip route
add distance=10 gateway=172.17.0.1 routing-mark=2isp

/ip route rule
add action=lookup-only-in-table dst-address=192.168.0.0/16 table=main
add src-address=192.168.0.24/32 table=2isp
```

Comment: что-то не так, второй isp не выпускает https://prnt.sc/t8hz18

Comment: нат забыли или что-то  ещё по настройке второго провайдера